# geocoding with for loop only the first used, and put in the dataframe (in R)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, geocoding

This is the time, when I need help, because I´ve tried everything to catch the problem with my FOR loop.
I want to geocode from address with an API, I use a very clarified function, and more data frames to arrange results for each step and check if there is a problem or not, but now I can´t find anything more...

**addresses**: is my data frame with **address** column, and the results will be put there

```
"address_ID","address","accuracy","lon_geop","lat_geop","address_geop","geopID","success"
1,"4 Kiricheneck 9990"
2,"10 Kiricheneck 9990"
3,"26 Kiricheneck 9990""
4,"27 Kiricheneck 9990"
5,"6 Avenue D'oberkorn 4640"
```

The code:

```
plcUrl <- "https://apiv3.geoportail.lu/geocode/search?queryString="
getGeoDetails <- function(address)
{   
  query <- paste(addresses$address)
  strurl <- as.character(paste(plcUrl,query))
  rd <- fromJSON(URLencode(strurl))
  df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(rd), nrow = 22, byrow = T),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  colnames(df)[1] <- "results_geop"  
answer <- data.frame(lat = NA, lon =  NA, accuray = NA, address_geop = NA, success = NA, geopID = NA)
answer$status <- df$results_geop[22]
#return Na's if we didn't get a match
  if (df$results_geop[22] != "TRUE")
  {
    return(answer)
  }   
#else, extract what we need from the GeoPortail server reply into a dataframe
answer$lat <- df$results_geop[9]
answer$lon <- df$results_geop[8]   
answer$accuracy <- df$results_geop[21]
answer$geopID <- df$results_geop[19]
answer$address_geop <- df$results_geop[6]
answer$success <- df$results_geop[22]
  return(answer)
}

#initialise a dataframe to hold the results
geocoded <- data.frame()
startindex <- 1
row_addresses <- as.numeric(rownames(addresses))

# Start the geocoding process - address by address
for (j in startindex:row_addresses)
{
#query the GeoPortail geocoder
  result = getGeoDetails(addresses[j]) 
  print(result$status)     
  result$index <- j
#append the answer to the results file
  geocoded <- rbind(geocoded, result)

#now we add all the results to the main data
addresses$lat_geop[j] <- geocoded$lat[j]
addresses$lon_geop[j] <- geocoded$lon[j]
addresses$accuracy[j] <- geocoded$accuracy[j]
addresses$address_geop[j] <- geocoded$address_geop[j]
addresses$geopID[j] <- geocoded$geopID[j]
addresses$success[j] <- geocoded$success[j]

return(j)}
```

And at the end:
*Warning message:
In startindex:row_addresses :
  numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used*

And the addresses data frame only has the first row with the good results, others are empty.
I´ve tried:

1. indexing: for(i in 1:x)
2. building empty data frame for the results and in the loop (index i): d[i, ] = c(x, y, z)
3. break command
4. next command

Nothing helped yet...Other for loops of mine do the job, so It´s very frustrating.

Comment: Most likely your mistake is here: `row_addresses <- as.numeric(rownames(addresses))` is returning a vector of 5 elements and then you are trying to use row_addresses in a following for loop index.  In the for loop just use `for (j in startindex:nrow(addresses))`

Comment: I tried, but nothing has changed:
for (j in startindex:nrow(addresses))
for (j in 1:nrow(addresses))
for (j in 1:5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make some usable data:

```
data.frame(
  address_ID = 1:5, 
  address = c(
    "4 Kiricheneck 9990", "10 Kiricheneck 9990", 
    "26 Kiricheneck 9990", "27 Kiricheneck 9990",
    "6 Avenue D'oberkorn 4640"
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> xdf
```

Now, let's make a proper API wrapper for that endpoint:

```
geoportail_geocode <- function(query) {

  suppressPackageStartupMessages({ # this makes it self-contained and quiet
    library(httr, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
    library(jsonlite, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
  })

  `%||%` <- function(x, y) { if (length(x)) x else y } # this makes the code below less 'if-else'y

  httr::GET(
    url  = "https://apiv3.geoportail.lu/geocode/search",
    httr::user_agent("geoportail_geocode R function used by me@example.com"), # you should add your email to this string
    query = list(
      queryString = query[1]
    )
  ) -> res

  httr::stop_for_status(res) # halts on API/network errors; you may not want this but it's standard practice in API packages

  out <- httr::content(res, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
  out <- jsonlite::fromJSON(out)

  if (length(out$success) && out$success) { # if the return looks valid

    # MAKES A MAJOR ASSUMPTION A Point IS BEING RETURNED
    # YOU SHOULD DO A *TON* MORE VALIDATION AND ERROR CHECKING

    ret <- out$results[,c("ratio", "name", "easting", "address", "northing", "matching street", "accuracy")]
    ret <- cbind.data.frame(ret, out$results$AddressDetails)
    ret$type <- out$results$geomlonlat$type %||% NA_character_
    ret$lng <- out$results$geomlonlat$coordinates[[1]][1] %||% NA_real_
    ret$lat <- out$results$geomlonlat$coordinates[[1]][2] %||% NA_real_
    ret$geom <- out$results$geom$type %||% NA_character_
    ret$geom_x <- out$results$geom$coordinates[[1]][1] %||% NA_real_
    ret$geom_y <- out$results$geom$coordinates[[1]][2] %||% NA_real_

    ret

  } else {
    warning("Error in geocoding")
    data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }

}
```

We'll do one:

```
str(geoportail_geocode(xdf$address[1]))
## 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  19 variables:
##  $ ratio            : num 1
##  $ name             : chr "4,Kiricheneck 9990 Weiswampach"
##  $ easting          : num 73344
##  $ address          : chr "4 Kiricheneck,9990 Weiswampach"
##  $ northing         : num 133788
##  $ matching street  : chr "Kiricheneck"
##  $ accuracy         : int 8
##  $ zip              : chr "9990"
##  $ locality         : chr "Weiswampach"
##  $ id_caclr_street  : chr "8188"
##  $ street           : chr "Kiricheneck"
##  $ postnumber       : chr "4"
##  $ id_caclr_building: chr "181679"
##  $ type             : chr "Point"
##  $ lng              : num 6.08
##  $ lat              : num 50.1
##  $ geom             : chr "Point"
##  $ geom_x           : num 73344
##  $ geom_y           : num 133788
```

And use the `tidyverse` to do them all and avoid `for` loops like the plague b/c this isn't Java or icky Python:

```
str(dplyr::bind_cols(
  xdf,
  purrr::map_df(xdf$address, geoportail_geocode)
))
## 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  21 variables:
##  $ address_ID       : int  1 2 3 4 5
##  $ address          : chr  "4 Kiricheneck 9990" "10 Kiricheneck 9990" "26 Kiricheneck 9990" "27 Kiricheneck 9990" ...
##  $ ratio            : num  1 1 1 1 1
##  $ name             : chr  "4,Kiricheneck 9990 Weiswampach" "10,Kiricheneck 9990 Weiswampach" "26,Kiricheneck 9990 Weiswampach" "27,Kiricheneck 9990 Weiswampach" ...
##  $ easting          : num  73344 73280 73203 73241 60462
##  $ address1         : chr  "4 Kiricheneck,9990 Weiswampach" "10 Kiricheneck,9990 Weiswampach" "26 Kiricheneck,9990 Weiswampach" "27 Kiricheneck,9990 Weiswampach" ...
##  $ northing         : num  133788 133732 133622 133591 65234
##  $ matching street  : chr  "Kiricheneck" "Kiricheneck" "Kiricheneck" "Kiricheneck" ...
##  $ accuracy         : int  8 8 8 8 8
##  $ zip              : chr  "9990" "9990" "9990" "9990" ...
##  $ locality         : chr  "Weiswampach" "Weiswampach" "Weiswampach" "Weiswampach" ...
##  $ id_caclr_street  : chr  "8188" "8188" "8188" "8188" ...
##  $ street           : chr  "Kiricheneck" "Kiricheneck" "Kiricheneck" "Kiricheneck" ...
##  $ postnumber       : chr  "4" "10" "26" "27" ...
##  $ id_caclr_building: chr  "181679" "181752" "181672" "181668" ...
##  $ type             : chr  "Point" "Point" "Point" "Point" ...
##  $ lng              : num  6.08 6.07 6.07 6.07 5.9
##  $ lat              : num  50.1 50.1 50.1 50.1 49.5
##  $ geom             : chr  "Point" "Point" "Point" "Point" ...
##  $ geom_x           : num  73344 73280 73203 73241 60462
##  $ geom_y           : num  133788 133732 133622 133591 65234
```

As noted in the function code, the `stop_for_status` call will kill the function so you may want to `warn_for_status` instead, check the status code of the response and return an empty `data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Comment: Today I've got this error after running the script (traceback)

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors 

4. out$results$geom$type %||% NA_character_ 
3. .f(.x[[i]], ...) 
2. map(.x, .f, ...) 
1. map_dfr(addresses$address, geoportail_geocode)

And with only 30 address it's working.

Comment: There are things in ALL CAPS in my answer noting where you need to think about making the function more robust. You should post a new question with the data that breaks the function if you refuse to do the debugging on your own. It's very likely either not returning a just a single `Point` or not a `Point` at all.

Answer (score 0):

the problem ist caused by `j in startindex:row_addresses` with `row_addresses` beeing a vector and not a single number. 
The for loop is intended to run from `startindex` till `row_addresses`, but since `row_addresses` is not a single number only the first element of the Vector is taken into account. 
Because both `startindex` and `row_addresses[1]` are 1, the loop just runs 1 time.

See the following code for an example and maybe a solution you could use

```
data_test <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 21:30)
startindex <- 1


row_addresses <- as.numeric(rownames(data_test))

row_addresses
> row_addresses
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10


# Problem: only the first element of row_addresses is used in the for loop
# So the loop runs from 1 to 1 - it stops after that
for(i in startindex:row_addresses)
{
  print(i)

}
> for(i in startindex:row_addresses)
+ {
+   print(i)
+   
+ }
[1] 1
Warning message:
In startindex:row_addresses :
  numerical expression has 10 elements: only the first used


for(i in startindex:NROW(data_test))
{
  print(i)

}
> for(i in startindex:NROW(data_test))
+ {
+   print(i)
+   
+ }
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
[1] 6
[1] 7
[1] 8
[1] 9
[1] 10
```